# Why return is not finishing function in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, p5.js

I Have this pen in codepe, and I Have a recursive function called '***getRandomPos***', the function fills an array called '***randomPos***' by randomly selected values from another array passed as an argument called '***dimensionArray***'

If the length of the new array is bigger than the parameter '**amount**' it should return the new array.

The function runs when you click the canvas.

If you have devtools open, as there is a debugger at line 17, you can go through the function's steps with the '**step over next function call**' button in devtools in chrome and you will see that after the length of the '***randomPos***' array is bigger than the '***amount***' argument, it should return the ***randomPos***.

But it doesnt.

It loops three times from line 30 to 31 three times.

I dont understand this, shouldnt return just stop the function and return ***randomPos***?

This is the code and here is the pen on codepen: [pen](https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/VWjoRP?editors=0010)

```
let getRandomFromArray = (items) => {
  let item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]
  return item
}

let rows = 20,
    cols = 50,
    randomXUnits = [],
    randomYUnits = [],
    canvasWidth = 500,
    canvasHeight = 200,
    gridXDiv = (canvasWidth/cols),
    gridYDiv = (canvasHeight/rows),
    randomPos = []


let getRandomPos = (amount, dimensionArray) => {
  debugger;
  let randomUnit = getRandomFromArray(dimensionArray)

    if(randomPos.length < amount){
      if(randomPos.includes(randomUnit)){
        getRandomPos(amount, dimensionArray) 
      }else{
        randomPos.push(randomUnit)
        getRandomPos(amount, dimensionArray) 
      }
    } 
  return randomPos  
}

let drawDivisions = (randomPosArray, dimension) => {
    randomPosArray.forEach( p => {
    fill(255)
    noStroke() 
    if(dimension === canvasWidth){
       rect(p,0,gridXDiv, canvasHeight)    
    }else{
       rect(0,p,canvasWidth, gridXDiv)   
     } 
  })
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(canvasWidth,canvasHeight)
  background(0)
  for (let i = gridXDiv; i < width-(gridXDiv-1); i+= gridXDiv) {
      randomXUnits.push(i)
    for (let j = gridYDiv; j < height-(gridYDiv-1); j+= gridYDiv) {
      if (randomYUnits.length < 20) {
        randomYUnits.push(j)
      }
    stroke(255)
    point(i,j)
    }
  }
}

function draw(){

}

function mouseClicked() {
  background(0)

  randomPos = []
  let usedPositionsInX = getRandomPos(3, randomXUnits)
  drawDivisions(usedPositionsInX,canvasHeight)


  let usedPositionsInY = getRandomPos(3, randomYUnits)
  drawDivisions(usedPositionsInY,canvasWidth)

}
```

Comment: Returning `randomPos` will in fact stop that execution of the function, so something else is going on. I suspect you're seeing all the other recurses.

Comment: Also note that you aren't returning from getRandomPos in every possible branch. If `randomPos.length < amount`, you don't return anything. You recurse by calling `getRandomPos` again, but you never return what it gives you.

Comment: a global mutable variable, very suspicious , inherently buggy

Comment: @Carcigenicate i dont return if `randomPos.length < amount` because if `randompos` length is smaller than `amount`, it must continue recursing... If `randompos` length is not smaller than `amount`, then it will return... Because i want the length of `randomPos` to be the same as `amount`

Comment: @GiorgioMartini If you don't return the result of a recursive call though, any results that that call creates will be lost. Unless you mutate a global of course, but recursion + mutable globals = sketchy business as someone else mentioned.

Comment: @GiorgioMartini and note, returning doesn't end *all* recursive calls, it only ends the current recursive call. Look up a implementation of a recursive factorial function. Note every branch ends in a return, yet, it's still able to keep searching for the solution. When recursing, every branch of execution needs to end in a return, obviously unless the language has implicit returns

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, but even if i add a return on the if statement it stillcontinues to recurse...? look: [link](https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/NgrVmK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using recursion and `getRandomPos` is not finishing on the recursion calls, the stack of calls are something like this:

- From mouse clicked, call `getRandomPos` with parameter 3 and randomXUnits

  - *0* `getRandomPos` test if randomPos is less than amount, **false** then

    - *1* `getRandomPos` test if randomPos is less than amount, **false** then

      - *2* `getRandomPos` test if randomPos is less than amount, **false** then

        - *3* `getRandomPos` test if randomPos is less than amount, **true** then
        - return *3*
      - return *2*
    - return *1*
  - return *0*

Comment: thanks, so how do I get getRandomPos to finish on the recursion calls? If adding returns on the main function and the if statement arent doing it?

Comment: IMHO this is not wrong, in fact is the natural behavior of recursion, as @Carcigenicate said: _look up an implementation of a recursive factorial function_, it has the same behavior. If you want the calls to your function finishes in the ´return´ statement then you have to change your code to use a loop like a for or while.

Comment: I have changed as you suggested to a a while loop, but im sure there must be a way to it with recursion.. I want to learn recursion and i've heard everything that can be done with loops can be done with recursion... I will ask another questions on how to achieve what I want with recursion.. because this question was really about why return was not finishing... thanks.